# Displaying number of items according to parameters passed xaml windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, data-binding, windows-phone-8

ok I have a MainPage.xaml

This passes a parameter to NextPage.xaml like this NextPage.xaml?count=10

Now i want to display 10 items on a long list selector, this number depends on the parameter passed how do i do this, can i bind data dynamically?

Comment: You have almost solved your problem yourself - just get the number you have passed with navigated to, and fill your LLS with list (observablecollection?) depending on this number. Can you show some more code with which you have problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the navigation parameter like this:

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("count"))
        {
            var countString = NavigationContext.QueryString["count"];
            var count = Int32.Parse(countString);
            // Create list
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
            {
                 MyLLSList.Add(new Item());
            }
        }
```

where MyLLSList is a property in your ViewModel to which you can bind as the LLS ItemSource.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Yep it did help me. I added the items to the long list selector. The first time I had created a list and added items to it. Did not work, butt this is good! I feel kinda stupid now :D Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pagina2.xaml?count=10", UriKind.Relative));
```

What you do. If you want do pass a varibale that contain the integer 10:

```
int getInteger= 10;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pagina2.xaml?count="+getInteger, UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I already passed the variable, just had some problems binding on the long list selector  on the navigated page